# Expandable List View Hide Item while using ViewHolder

Tags: android, expandablelistview, show-hide, android-viewholder

I am writing an application where I need to hide elements of Expandable List View.

This is what I am doing to achieve it.

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        CardHeaderInfo headerInfo = (CardHeaderInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.card_group_view, null);
        }

        if(groupPosition < validChild) {
            TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

To optimize work here I have used [ViewHolder](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) concept but with this if start to scroll list, then elements get shuffle even some of variable replaced with hide view.

Is there any way to get rid out of this issue while using ViewHolder thing?

Answer (score 0):

I got this by adding another line to visible already hide element :

```
if(groupPosition < validChild) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ****
            TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```